# Why structured binding fails with 'std::tie' d objects?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, structured-bindings, std-tie

I was curious to do [this asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194761/find-the-neighbors-in-stdset)
problem in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    const std::set<int> s{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    auto iter = s.find(5);
    using IterType = decltype(iter);

    // using `std::array` works fine!
    const auto& [pv1, nxt1] = std::array<IterType, 2>{std::prev(iter), std::next(iter)};
    std::cout <<"using std::array<IterType, 2> :"<< *pv1 << " " << *nxt1 << '\n'; // prints: 4 6

    // using ` std::make_tuple` works fine!
    const auto& [pv2, nxt2] = std::make_tuple(std::prev(iter), std::next(iter));
    std::cout << "using std::make_tuple :" << *pv2 << " " << *pv2 << '\n';        // prints: 4 6

    // using `std::tie` deduction happens in MSVC, but not in GCC and Clang
    const auto& [pv3, nxt3] = std::tie(std::prev(iter), std::next(iter));
    // following is an assertion failure in MSVC with /O2  /std:c++17
    std::cout << "using std::tie :" << *pv3 << " " << *nxt3<< '\n';
}
```

I `std::tie` d the returned iterators of `std::prev` and `std::next`, and allowed the
structured binding to do the `auto` deduction.

```
const auto& [pv3, nxt3] = std::tie(std::prev(iter), std::next(iter));
```

looks like the only compiler it allows is *MSVC v19.14* with `/O2  /std:c++17`!
The *GCC 9.1* and *clang 8.0* does not agree with that. See in the on-line compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/DTb_OZ

GCC says:

```
<source>:23:28: error: no matching function for call to 'tie'
        const auto& [pv3, nxt3] = std::tie(std::prev(iter), std::next(iter));
                                  ^~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/tuple:1605:5: note: candidate function [with _Elements = <std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>>] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
    tie(_Elements&... __args) noexcept
^
```

Clang says:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:23:46: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>'
   23 |  const auto& [pv3, nxt3] = std::tie(std::prev(iter), std::next(iter));
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from <source>:5:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/tuple:1611:19: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'constexpr std::tuple<_Elements& ...> std::tie(_Elements& ...) [with _Elements = {std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}]'
 1611 |     tie(_Elements&... __args) noexcept
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

**Looking to the example given in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Notes)
is MSVC is correct? or Who is(are) right here and why?**

Interestingly while running the

```
std::cout << "using std::tie :" << *pv3 << " " << *nxt3<< '\n';
```

gives me

[image]

(in *MSVS 2019*, `/std:c++17`)

Comment: Enable `/Za` flag to compiler, then the code will be refused. MVSC has extenstion which allows to bind temps to Lvalue reference. `tie` gets Lvalue references, but `prev` , `next` returns temporary.

Comment: I don't think structured bindings have anything to do with this question. Try `const auto& x = ...` instead of them and the problem remains.

Comment: @MaxLanghof When the problem gets clear from a closer look, sometimes the question(s)(or initial intuitions) that had, in the beginning, maybe meaningless.  That's what happened with me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [[tuple.creation]/tie](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.creation#itemdecl:3):

> ```
> template<class... TTypes>
>   constexpr tuple<TTypes&...> tie(TTypes&... t) noexcept;
> ```

Here, the arguments are non-const lvalue references.  `std::prev(iter)` and `std::next(iter)` cannot be bound to lvalue references, so the code should be rejected.  The reason why MSVC accepts this is explained in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196890/why-structured-binding-fails-with-stdtie-d-objects#comment100902301_57196890):

> Enable `/Za` flag to compiler, then the code will be refused. MVSC
>   [sic] has extenstion which allows to bind temps to Lvalue reference.
>   `tie` gets Lvalue references, but `prev`, `next` returns temporary. –
>   [rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8950365) 2019-07-25
>   07:52:58Z